# What's the name of this entropy based on particle density?

Tags: entropy, terminology, density, information

Say, at time $t$, the particle density in space is $\rho(\vec{x},t)$ and this distribution is normalized such that $\int d^3 \vec{x} \rho(\vec{x},t) = 1$. We can then associated a value similar to Shanon entropy to the system:

$S(t) = \int d^3 \vec{x} \rho(\vec{x},t) \ln \rho(\vec{x},t) $

There might be a normalization factor (eg. depends on how space is divided into voxels), but the idea is that it's a form of entropy that depends on particle density at a given time in space. The problem is I read about this kind of entropy a very long ago, and I can't remember the name for it. Do you know how this entropy is called? It should be noted that this question is based solely on my memory, so some of the details might be a little wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you want real space and not in phase space?

Comment: Yeah, if it's phase space then it's conventional.